# In Eclipse, xml and xhtml files show unsaved state when switching git branches

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm on a Mac and I'm using JBoss Developer Studio (Eclipse Indigo) and when I switch branches in Git, I'm experiencing an issue where my xhtml files are showing as unsaved (There is an asterisk in the tab indicating that changes have been made).

My java files refresh fine, and I do have "Refresh using native hooks or poling" and "Refresh on Access" both checked in Preferences > General > Workspace.

The behavior I'm experiencing is as follows:

1) Let's say I have multiple .java and and .xhtml files open. Both will be in a saved state (No asterisk in the tab indicating a modified file that needs saving)

2) I'll switch branches in git

3) The .java files will be refreshed just fine and will remain in a saved state, while the .xhtml and .xml files will refresh as well, but will be in a modified/unsaved state (there will be an asterisk at the top showing modifications)

I then have to manually save each of the files to get them in saved state.  Has anyone else experienced this issue before or have any idea on how to solve this issue?  Much thanks in advance.